# Using file command to know language of file

Tags: linux, files

How can I use file command to know which language my file is written? File command use language tests to get the language file is written, but it seems it do not execute when first two tests - file type and magic number execute properly. How to check only the language a file is written in?

Comment: what if a file contained words on multiple languages?

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible? If a file contains the word *pain*, for example, that could be English for *hurt* or French for *bread*. In either case, the file could be encoded as ASCII or as UTF (or, probably, various others). How could a computer know what language it is in? Not even a human would be able to guess. It gets simpler with non-Latin alphabets but, again, the same alphabet is often shared by multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU `file`, with option `-e` you can exclude tests:

```
file -e soft
```

should skip the "magic" test.

Answer (score 0):

### File extension

Files can have or not have any file extension and still be usable for their purpose.  They are usually used in the context of the language itself.

That said, you can frequently use the file extension as a usually reliable proxy.